# jw player vast tag not playing in ipad (video content is working fine)

Tags: ios, ipad, jwplayer, ads, vast

I am using JW Player in my Ipad app. When I checking in the browser the vast tag is playing fine and after that content is loading.

But unlike that in Ipad VAST tag not playing and do skipped. Then content video is playing. I am using a crossdomain URL for VAST tag. But I have given the Access Control Allow Origin. But there is no good sound.

Is anyone experienced in this..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using jwplayer ios sdk, or unpacking the player for web in WebView?

Comment: hi, i am using webview. not the jwplayer ios sdk.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of ad creative is returned by your ad tag? If it is a .swf or .flv, then it will not play on an iPad or any mobile device. Make sure to request MP4 or VPAID 2.0 ads from your ad network. You will also need JW Player 7.1 or higher for VPAID 2.0 support.

We love Stack Overflow, but we don't check for new posts very often. If you want support from JW Player directly, please go to http://jwplayer.com/support/

Comment: I already post this in JW Player support. Here is the link for the question.

I am using mp4 video tag. Also i tested in your tester. There is no error I am getting. Ad is working perfectly fine.

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/questions/14563109-vast-tag-video-not-playing-ad-is-skipping-?new=14563109